# kafka MirrorMaker 2.0 does not replicate data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to replicate Kafka cluster with MirrorMaker 2.0.
I am using following mm2.properties:

```
# mm2.properties
clusters=source, dest

source.bootstrap.servers=kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092
dest.bootstrap.servers=kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092

source->dest.enabled=true
```

I can see that when MirrorMaker starts, it creates its own topics. For example on source cluster it creates: **mm2-configs.dest.internal** with following content:

```
{
   "properties":{
      "connector.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
      "source.cluster.producer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "source.cluster.alias":"dest",
      "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "target.cluster.producer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "enabled":"false",
      "target.cluster.admin.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "target.cluster.alias":"source",
      "target.cluster.consumer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "name":"MirrorSourceConnector",
      "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "source.cluster.admin.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "source.cluster.consumer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092"
   }
}
```

and at destination cluster **mm2-configs.source.internal** topic with following content:

```
{
   "properties":{
      "connector.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
      "source.cluster.producer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "source.cluster.alias":"source",
      "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "target.cluster.producer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "enabled":"true",
      "target.cluster.admin.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "target.cluster.alias":"dest",
      "target.cluster.consumer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "name":"MirrorSourceConnector",
      "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-4:39092,kafka-5:49092,kafka-6:59092",
      "source.cluster.admin.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092",
      "source.cluster.consumer.bootstrap.servers":"kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:19092,kafka-3:29092"
   }
}
```

But when I am trying to send messages to source cluster (kafka-1,kafka-2,kafka-3) - nothing copied to the second cluster.

What do I miss?

Appreciate any help
Thx,

Comment: How about starting simpler? Remove Docker. Run one broker per physical host?

Comment: @cricket_007 Since I have only my laptop, do you mean on VMs? And, by the way, the old MirrorMaker (1.x) works OK with dockers

Comment: Anything can work with Docker, sure. My point is that you should create a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand what do you mean :) But I have only one physical computer (my laptop) and I need at least 2, and I thought that Docker is the solution for this. But I'll try with only one broker, thx

Answer (score 1):

mm2 works well in standalone ( single node ) mode, but when it comes to the cluster there is a bug.

The details have been reported here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-710%3A+Full+support+for+distributed+mode+in+dedicated+MirrorMaker+2.0+clusters

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30303656)

Comment: Hmm, why it does not really answer the question? The issue is it doesn't mirror data to dest cluster which is fully described in the link I put in it. 

There is workaround that is restart mm2 everytime you create new topic so data will sync on dest topic

Answer (score 0):

Your config files look ok. However, those bootstrap server ports look off.  `19092`, `29092`, etc.  Those are *typically* `9092` only.  Can you try changing those back to `9092`?

Comment: Hi, thx. I am running all this in docker. And seems MirrorMaker succeeds to interact with Kafka, since it creates its internal topics

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found (with help of my friend) what was the problem. In case when topic does **NOT** exist before starting MirrorMaker, replication won't happen. Topic should exist in source Kafka cluster.

I used Java producer with topic auto create enabled. Seems, automatic topic creation, doesn't trigger MirrorMaker to start replication.

I don't really know if it's **as designed** behavior when defining `source->dest.enabled=true` or maybe related to solved few days ago bug: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/7745.